# `gulp-inject` throw error as `Did you mean to provide it for `gulp.src` perhaps?`

Tags: gulp, gulp-inject

In my application I am using `gulp-inject` but I am getting error while I run my `gulpfile.js`  how to fix it?

`console` :

```
PS F:\Nissan-Gulp> gulp
[14:38:38] Using gulpfile F:\Nissan-Gulp\gulpfile.js
[14:38:38] Starting 'server'...
[14:38:38] Finished 'server' after 22 ms
[14:38:38] Starting 'inject'...
[14:38:38] 'inject' errored after 19 ms
[14:38:38] Error in plugin 'gulp-inject'
Message:
    There is no `read` option. Did you mean to provide it for `gulp.src` perhaps?
[14:38:38] Server started http://localhost:9000
[14:38:38] LiveReload started on port 35729
```

my code :

```
gulp.task( "inject", function( ) {
    var sources = gulp.src(['./app/scripts/**/*.js', './app/stylesheets/**/*.css' ], {read: false}, {relative: true});
    return gulp.src('./app/index.html')
    .pipe(inject(sources, {
        read: false,
        ignorePath: '/app'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'));
});
```

my html code :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css">
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- inject:css -->
    <!-- endinject -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- inject:js -->
    <!-- endinject -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
.pipe(inject(sources, {
    read: false,
    ignorePath: '/app'
}))
```

to

```
.pipe(inject(sources, { ignorePath: '/app' } ))
```

Your sources variable already has the read option set - it is an option to gulp.src not gulp-inject.  That is why it should be within the argument list for gulp.src as you correctly have it for var sources:

```
var sources = gulp.src['./app/scripts/**/*.js', './app/stylesheets/**/*.css' ], {read: false}, {relative: true});
```

ignorePath is an inject option; read is not listed there. [gulp-inject description](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject)